# USING PIVOT ORACLE

Tags: oracle, pivot

Tenho esse resultado:

> Ana   DEC 123 7   2016    1GG
>
> Ana   DEC 123 3   2016    1GG
>
> Ana   DEC 123 3   2016    1GG
>
> Ana   JCM 123 5   2017    1GG
>
> Edson DES 123 11  2016    1GG
>
> Edson DES 123 3   2017    1GG

Estou usando esse PLSQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        C.DS_MAGISTRADO,
        TIPO_ATO,
        NR_PROCESSO,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT_REGISTRO) MES,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT_REGISTRO) ANO,
        B.DS_SISTEMA
    FROM  
        PROD_ATO A
        INNER JOIN REF_SISTEMA B ON A.ID_SISTEMA = B.ID_SISTEMA
        INNER JOIN REF_MAGISTRADO C ON A.ID_MAGISTRADO = C.ID_MAGISTRADO
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT_REGISTRO) IN (2016, 2017)
        AND NR_PROCESSO = '123'

    GROUP BY
        C.DS_MAGISTRADO,
        TIPO_ATO,
        NR_PROCESSO,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT_REGISTRO),
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT_REGISTRO),
        B.DS_SISTEMA
)
PIVOT
    (COUNT(TIPO_ATO) FOR TIPO_ATO IN ('DEC', 'DES', 'EXT', 'HOM', 'JCM', 'JSM'))
ORDER BY
    DS_MAGISTRADO,
    MES,
    ANO;
```

O resultado deveria ser na coluna 'DEC' = 2 para o Ano = 2016 e o mês = 3, porem, está me mostrando como 'DEC' = 1.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse comportamento é causado pelo uso do GROUP BY na sub-query. Da forma como está a ser usado tem um comportamento semelhante ao uso do predicado DISTINCT. A sua sub-query está a devolver

```
Ana   DEC 123  7 2016 1GG 
Ana   DEC 123  3 2016 1GG 
Ana   JCM 123  5 2017 1GG 
Edson DES 123 11 2016 1GG
Edson DES 123  3 2017 1GG
```

ao invés de

```
Ana   DEC 123  7 2016 1GG 
Ana   DEC 123  3 2016 1GG 
Ana   DEC 123  3 2016 1GG
Ana   JCM 123  5 2017 1GG 
Edson DES 123 11 2016 1GG
Edson DES 123  3 2017 1GG
```

Experimente remover a agregação e verá que obtem o resultado esperado.

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT C.DS_MAGISTRADO,
           TIPO_ATO,
           NR_PROCESSO,
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DT_REGISTRO) MES,
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT_REGISTRO) ANO,
           B.DS_SISTEMA
    FROM  
        PROD_ATO A
        INNER JOIN REF_SISTEMA B ON A.ID_SISTEMA = B.ID_SISTEMA
        INNER JOIN REF_MAGISTRADO C ON A.ID_MAGISTRADO = C.ID_MAGISTRADO
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DT_REGISTRO) IN (2016, 2017)
      AND NR_PROCESSO = '123'
)
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(TIPO_ATO) FOR TIPO_ATO IN ('DEC', 'DES', 'EXT', 'HOM', 'JCM', 'JSM')
) Piv
ORDER BY DS_MAGISTRADO, MES, ANO
;
```