# Como fazer valores de linhas retornarem como colunas em um select no Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select

O select que eu fiz está retornando conforma exemplo abaixo:

Select:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS total,b."Nome",a."Funcionalidade",
  DECODE(a."Funcionalida", 
          128, 'ProdutoA',
          4, 'ProdutoB',
          512, 'ProdutoC'
          ) tipo  
          FROM s."Documentos" a
          JOIN s."Usuarios" b
  ON a."IdTecnico" = b."Id"
GROUP BY a."IdTecnico",b."Nome",a."Funcionalidade" ORDER BY b."Nome"
```

Retorno:

```
total | nome | tipo     
2     |Joao  |ProdutoA
51    |Joao  |ProdutoB        
7     |Joao  |ProdutoC   
4     |Maria |ProdutoA
30    |Maria |ProdutoB 
1     |Pedro |ProdutoA
58    |Pedro |ProdutoB        
3     |Pedro |ProdutoC
```

Como posso fazer o retorno com os valores `ProdutoA`, `ProdutoB`, `ProdutoC`, como títulos das colunas,conforme abaixo:

Retorno esperado:

```
    Nome | ProdutoA | ProdutoB| ProdutoC
    Joao | 2        | 51      | 7  
    Maria| 4        | 30      | 0  
    Pedro| 1        | 58      | 3
```

Comment: isso se chama "pivot", procure que tem outras perguntas relacionadas aqui no SOpt, como essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224886/using-pivot-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com o select:

```
SELECT 
    b."Nome",
    SUM(case when a."Funcionalidade" = 128 then 1 else 0 end) ProdutoA,
    SUM(case when a."Funcionalidade" = 4 then 1 else 0 end) ProdutoB,
    SUM(case when a."Funcionalidade" = 512 then 1 else 0 end) ProdutoC
        
FROM s."Documentos" a
INNER JOIN s."Usuarios" b ON a."IdTecnico" = b."Id"
WHERE    
GROUP BY b."Nome"       
ORDER BY b."Nome"
```